# Any API to get notification before any file gets deleted in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, file-recovery

I want to recover the file which has been deleted recently. Is there any API in android to get notify before the file gets deleted or to recover recently deleted files?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

no, there is no such API, you can however use file observer to be notified about file deletion

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt. Using file observer we can get notification after the file gets deleted. I want to take back up of the file before its get deleted. How can i achieve this? or is it possible to recover the file once it get deleted?

Comment: you cannot do this, its quite logical: if it were possible then File.delete() would be blocking operation but from obvious reasons it cannotbe so